# Updated geth, now I am re-syncing the whole blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

This is the first time I have updated geth.

I was at a build of geth from several weeks ago, and this morning I updated to 1.4.12.  I downloaded the pre-built binary to a new location on disk, started it up, then ran geth attach and was surprised that my ether account balance was 0.  I then realized that the whole blockchain was re-syncing by running web3.eth.syncing.

I am assuming that when the sync is complete, I will be back to normal, but I am guessing there is a better way to do this?  How does one update to a new version of geth without having to go get the whole blockchain again?  Or have I misunderstood what is happening?